# Is every positive integer the sum of 1 square number, 1 pentagonal number, and 1 hexagonal number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

I found this interesting conjecture, but maybe I'm not the first to state it. I have tested it for the first $10^4$ positive integers, but that is not a proof. Can anybody prove or disprove this conjecture?

> **Every positive integer can be written as the sum of 1 square number, 1 pentagonal number, and 1 hexagonal number.**

**Note**:

Square numbers are generated by the formula, $S_{n}=n^{2}$.
The first ten square numbers are:

```
0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,...
```

Pentagonal numbers are generated by the formula, $P_{n}=\frac{1}{2}n(3n-1)$.
The first ten pentagonal numbers are:

```
0, 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, 51, 70, 92, 117,...
```

Hexagonal numbers are generated by the formula, $H_{n} = n(2n-1)$.
The first ten Hexagonal numbers are:

```
0, 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 120, 153,...
```

---

Here are the solutions for the first 10 positive integers.

Numbers    =     Square + Pentagon + Hexagon

```
1    =    0    +    1    +    0
2    =    1    +    1    +    0
3    =    1    +    1    +    1
4    =    4    +    0    +    0
5    =    0    +    5    +    0
6    =    1    +    5    +    0
7    =    1    +    5    +    1
8    =    1    +    1    +    6
9    =    4    +    5    +    0
10   =    9    +    1    +    0
```

Comment: I tested it using computer, but it is impossible to write all the test result here. Anybody who know programming can test it to.

Comment: Okay just checking; since in standard notation $10.000 = 10$. You could paste your program output at http://pastebin.com/ and link to it from here, saving people the time to reproduce it.

Comment: Related theorems are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem, but I would be surprised if they could be used to prove your hypothesis easily.

Comment: I tested it up to 100000 and it holds. Further more, the number of different sums adding to n seems to grow with n. Here is a graph:
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160815/kk2875aa.png

Comment: @user21820 '.' and ',' are both standard. Both are widely used.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0635v3

Comment: @MichaelStocker: They are widely used in layman language, yes, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping, and also most modern programming languages use "." for only the decimal point. It is really a pity people up to today cannot come to consensus on these basic important notations. Ever heard of http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-27509559?

Comment: @WillJagy: Nice find! So it's still an open problem?

Comment: @user21820 I suppose so. It is not difficult to prove these things when we do not require that the variables be non-negative,  I did that much at the earlier question. In brief, positivity of variables is not a natural condition for quadratic forms. It is a natural condition for theta series of various types, so modular forms work. This means it may be possible to prove these conjectures for sufficiently large numbers, without being able to prove it for small numbers.

Comment: @user21820 We are very off topic here :P. 
It is not only laymans language. In the wiki article you find two long lists of languages using '.' or ','. We are on an english site , so I guess we should stick to the english version.
Your bbc link doesn't for me btw.

Comment: @MichaelStocker: Try http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-27509559 or search google for "great miscalculations the french railway error and 10 others". My point is that it is a relatively simple matter to agree on a standard. After all we managed to do it for the decimal digits, so why not the decimal point too? Don't you find it silly that such an 'advanced' race cannot even standardize basic counting notation?

Comment: @user21820 Oh, I do agree wholeheartedly. This should be standardized, as should many other things. But it hasn't yet. The closest we probably came to is: "The 22nd General Conference on Weights and Measures declared in 2003 that "the symbol for the decimal marker shall be either the point on the line or the comma on the line""